# Rails 3+ Gluing (merging) up instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So here is example

```
class Foos
 has_many :bars
 belongs_to :cities
end

class Bar
 belongs_to :foo
end
```

So, if i have Foo instance named "Foo1" that belong to city numbered 1 and have another Foo instance named "Foo1" that also belongs to city no 1 how I can glue it up if they both have DIFFERENTS Bars to one Foo instance that will be include all that Bars?

Thx. Best reards

Comment: Delete one foo and add its bar to the other foo. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founded Active Record merge lib that helps

```
        module Merge

      # True if self is safe to merge with +object+, ie they are more or less equal.
      # Default implementation compares all attributes except id and metadata.
      # Can be overridden in specific models that have a neater way of comparison.
      def merge_equal?(object)
        object.instance_of?(self.class) and merge_attributes == object.merge_attributes
      end

      MERGE_INDIFFERENT_ATTRIBUTES = %w(id created_at updated_at).freeze
      MERGE_EXCLUDE_ASSOCIATIONS = [].freeze

      # Attribute hash used for comparison.
      def merge_attributes
        merge_attribute_names.inject({}) do |attrs, name|
          attrs[name] = self[name]
          attrs
        end
      end

      # Names of the attributes that should be merged.
      def merge_attribute_names
        attribute_names - MERGE_INDIFFERENT_ATTRIBUTES
      end

      # Names of associations excluded from the merge. 
      # Override if the model has multiple scoped associations,
      # that can all be retrieved by a single has_many association.
      def merge_exclude_associations
        MERGE_EXCLUDE_ASSOCIATIONS
      end

      # Merge this object with the given +objects+. 
      # This object will serve as the master,
      # blank attributes will be taken from the given objects, in order.
      # All associations to +objects+ will be assigned to +self+.
      def merge!(*objects)
        transaction do
          merge_attributes!(*objects)
          merge_association_reflections.each do |r|
            local = send(r.name)
            objects.each do |object|
              if r.macro == :has_one
                other = object.send(r.name)
                if local and other
                  local.merge!(other)
                elsif other
                  send("#{r.name}=", other)
                end
              else
                other = object.send(r.name) - local
                # May be better to compare without the primary key attribute instead of setting it.
                other.each {|o| o[r.foreign_key] = self.id}
                other.reject! {|o| local.any? {|l| merge_if_equal(l,o) }}
                local << other
              end
            end
          end
          objects.each {|o| o.reload and o.destroy unless o.new_record?}
        end
      end

      def merge_attributes!(*objects)
        blank_attributes = merge_attribute_names.select {|att| self[att].blank?}
        until blank_attributes.empty? or objects.empty?
          object = objects.shift
          blank_attributes.reject! do |att|
            if val = object[att] and not val.blank?
              self[att] = val
            end
          end
        end
        save!
      end

      private

      def merge_association_reflections
        self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.select do |r| 
          [:has_many, :has_one, :has_and_belongs_to_many].include?(r.macro) and 
          not r.options[:through] and 
          not merge_exclude_associations.include?(r.name.to_sym)
        end
      end

      def merge_if_equal(master, object)
        if master.merge_equal?(object)
          master.merge!(object) ; true
        end
      end

    end

    ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval { include Merge }

    # Compatibility with ActiveRecord 2.x
    class ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection
      alias :foreign_key :primary_key_name unless method_defined? :foreign_key
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo1, foo2 = Foo.where(:name => "Foo1", :city_id => some_id).limit(2)
foo1.bars << foo2.bars
foo2.bars = []
foo2.delete
```

Comment: nope. I can have "Foo1" in city 1 and "Foo1" in city 2 and this is different foos that i don't want to gluing. Foo.find_by_name_and_city returning only one record anyway

Comment: I assumed you already have the Foo instances, and your problem was to move te Bar instances from one to the other. If the problem is to find the coincidences, you have to state it better.

Comment: Forget abut the finder. You will load the Foo instances in any way you want. Then, one by one, apply the described process.

Comment: So, i assumed that rails have good methood for gluing. Because my model in role Foo has ~ 10 associations.